# View a Dashboard by Different Years

Tags: dashboard, filters

I have created a Sales Dashboard that shows information on Fiscal Year.

However, I need the same Dashboard to display data for previous years as well.

I tried to use a filter on the Dashboard, but every time it changes, takes about 15 (fifteen) minutes for the data to refresh.

I removed the Dates from the reports, fort this to work, since if I put a date filter on the report, the Dashboard filter and the report filter than negate each-other and I will get a 'zero' results dashboard.

Any idea on how to have such 'Yearly' dashboards that can look on historical years as well?

- Please do not suggest duplicate all the reports

Comment: Would grouping the results by FY help or be possible?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking a look at [Analytic Snapshots](http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/data_about_analytic_snap.htm) it gives you the ability to take snapshots of your data, store them in an object, and use them in reports/dashboards for historical data analysis

Comment: I looked at it, I need to create a specific report per year per object. so next year, I will need to create a new report. Not the solution I was looking for.